# Can you take a enchantment off a weapon

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

Is there a way for the enchantment to be taken a way form the sword because the enchantment is not the best, o and that it gives me my XP back so I can in chant it to something better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get your XP back from enchanting (on Xbox or otherwise). Once you've spent it, it's gone for good.

To *remove* an enchantment from a tool, you'll need to combine the tool on the workbench with another tool of the same type and material (both diamond pickaxes for example). Note that this will remove the second tool, but:

> The repaired item will have usage points equal to the sum of the old items' usage points plus a 'repair bonus' of 5% (10% before 1.4)
>
> - [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Item_repair)

So to remove the enchantment, without wasting a whole tool, you'll have to use both items to at least below 50% health, and then combine them. This will remove the enchantments from the tool.

---

Unfortunately, the Xbox version hasn't released the [Anvil](http://minecraft.wikia.com/wiki/Anvil) yet, although it's on their [planned upcoming features](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Xbox_360_Edition_upcoming_features). With the Anvil you'll be able to combine/repair tools (similar to the workbench), except they can ***keep and combine their enchantments***.

You can then also enchant books, and combine them on the Anvil with tools to pick and choose the enchantments you want on your tools.

The only downside to the Anvil, is that it costs XP to use it. Meaning that enchanting this way actually costs around double XP, as you need to enchant books (-XP) and then combine the book with a tool (-XP).

**See also:**

- [What enchantments can books have?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96986/what-enchantments-can-books-have)
- [What's the point of an enchanted book?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/108655/whats-the-point-of-an-enchanted-book)
- [Are enchanted books or direct enchanting better for rare enchantments?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/116179/are-enchanted-books-or-direct-enchanting-better-for-rare-enchantments)

Comment: @Thebestwithin no problem, glad I could help :)

Comment: This answer is now out of date. Minecraft 1.14 added the grindstone which allows you to get XP back from enchantments. (Also presumably xbox edition eventually got anvil, and anyway now xbox runs bedrock)